# Build error- The event "This Event" is never used

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am trying to test a C# program and have received the "Event is never used (!) " error. It says Build: 1 succeed. I know a little bit about VB.net but know nothing about C in general. Can anyone suggest something that might either fix the error or maybe just ground it or make it a hollow statement so it passes? Here is what I have. I will mark the trouble maker with @@@ troublemaker @@@

```
public static class Debug {
    // ReSharper disable once EventNeverInvoked
    public static event EventHandler<EventArg<string>> @@@ DebugOutput; @@@

    [Conditional("PRINTDEBUG")] [Conditional("DEBUG")] internal static void SendDebug(string message, params object[] args) {
#if NO_DEBUG_PRINT // Ignore it!
#else
        var dbg = DebugOutput;
        if(dbg == null || message == null)
            return;
        message = args.Length == 0 ? message : string.Format(message, args);
        dbg(null, new EventArg<string>(message));
#endif
    }
}
```

DebugOutput has a green underline. Is there a name for that for future reference? 
Thanks in advance for any help. Maybe I will learn something with this.

Comment: If build succeeded, then this is just a warning, and you can create code to use that event when you are ready.  Are you unable to run the app?

Comment: That's not an error, but a mere warning. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/trevor/archive/2008/08/14/c-warning-cs0067-the-event-event-is-never-used.aspx for recommendations on how to suppress it.

Comment: Do I delete my post. I think @AndreyChernyakhovskiy Provided me with what I was looking for.

Comment: As long as I get it to build I can note it and it will get fixed properly. But it is telling me a project with an output type class library cannot be started directly?

Comment: @King96 Since your project is a class library, you're creating a .dll. You either need to create a test project or some kind of website / executable that uses your library